# How is a process blocked by epoll_wait awakened?

Tags: select, operating-system, system, file-descriptor, epoll

If the list of ready file descriptors is empty, then epoll_wait() blocks. In this case, the process calling epoll_wait() must go in a blocked state. Which means the process must be sleeping.

Assuming that one of the watched file descriptors becomes ready, how is the calling process awakened by the kernel? And how does it resume its execution?

Comment: Same as all I/O - an I/O completion interrupt runs the comms driver.  The driver then signals something, (often a semaphore), requests a scheduling/dispatch run upon exit from interrupt state.  Your poll, that was waiting on the semaphore/whatever, is set ready/running.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, do you have any resources or links which explains this ?